# Let $A\subset(1, \infty)$ satisfy the following property : $x \in A$ iff $x^2 \in A$. What are the possible values of $m(A)$ if $A$ is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Here I'm assuming $A$ is (Lebesgue) measurable, and $m(A)$ is its usual Lebesgue measure. It didn't take me long until I felt that either $m(A)=0$ or $m(A)=\infty$. I'm not sure if that's indeed the case (and even so, if my proof is correct), so I decided to post it here to double check. My idea was as follows:

Firstly, notice that the set $A=\{2^{2^k} : k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ satisfies the above property. Since $A$ is countable, we can have $m(A)=0$. However, I claim that, if $m(A)>0$, then in fact $m(A)=\infty$. To see why, notice that by countable additivity the positivity of $m(A)$ implies that $A \cap (n, n+1]$ has positive measure for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Fix some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for which this is true, and let $I:=(n, n+1]$. Since
$$n^{2^j} > \left(\frac{n+1}{n} \right)^{2^k}$$ for sufficiently large $j \in \mathbb{N}$, we know that, given any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we can find $j \in \mathbb{N}$ for which the sets $(n^{2^k}, (n+1)^{2^k}]$ and $(n^{2^{k+j}}, (n+1)^{2^{k+j}}$ are disjoint. Because of the stated property of $A$, there are as many elements of $A$ in $(n^{2^k}, (n+1)^{2^k}]$ as there are in $(n^{2^{k+j}}, (n+1)^{2^{k+j}}$. So the measures of $A$ restricted to these intervals coincide. Following this reasoning, we can find infinitely many intervals of this form, say, $\{I_l\}_{l \in S}$, where $I_l:=(n^{2^l}, (n+1)^{2^l}]$ and $S$ is a countable subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Therefore, we have that
$$m(A) \geq m(\bigcup (A \cap I_l))=\sum_{l \in S} m(A \cap I_l)=\sum_{l \in S} m(A \cap I)=\sum_{l=1}^{\infty} m(A \cap I)=\infty$$
since we are adding $m(A \cap I)>0$ infinitely many times.
Therefore, any set $A$ with the above property either is null or has infinite measure. $\blacksquare$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Concerning the countable example you propose, it seems that $4\in A$ but $2\notin A$. I believe you need $\{2^{2^k}: k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ . So $\sqrt{2}\in A$ etc.

Comment: @GReyes True. I will make sure to edit that accordingly. Thank you!

Comment: Also, I think your proof can be simplified, using the same idea.

Comment: @GReyes How so? By the way, now that I fixed the exponent mistake, do you think my proof looks valid?

Comment: I think it is valid, but I do not quite get why you need the inequality. If, for example, the intersection with $[n_1,n_1+1)$ has positive measure, you can choose $n_2=n_1^{2^{k_1}}>n_1+1$ and then $n_3=n_1^{2^{k_2}}>(n_2+1)^{2^{k_1}}$ and so on recursively. You end up with a countable family of disjoint pieces of $A$ whose measure is at least that of the first piece (which is your idea).

Comment: @GReyes I see. I guess I was just trying to explicitly argue why we can choose integers $n_k$ in that manner, but I think that's not necessary.

Comment: Since all $n_i>1$, the possibility of choosing the powers is straightforward.

Comment: This appears to be completely false "Because of the stated property of A
, there are as many elements of $A$.... So the measures of A
 restricted to these intervals coincide"  Why on earth would the cardinality of an infinite set tell you anything about its measure?  I'm afraid unless I'm missing something obvious this proof idea doesn't really work, unless you invoke a fact about Lebesgue measure increasing under maps that expand distances.

Comment: As @MW pointed out, the argument "Because of the stated property of $A$, there are as many elements of $A$ .... So the measures of $A$ restricted to these intervals coincide" is incorrect. Two uncountable sets may have the same cardinality and different (Lebesgue) measures. For instance, $[0,1]$ and $K$, the Cantor set, have the same cardinality, but the measure of $[0,1]$ is $1$ and the measure of $K$ is $0$. The easiest way to correct that step in your proof is to use the Theorem of Change of Variable, but then there is a much simple and direct proof. See the proof I posted as my answer.

Comment: @Ramiro thank you for pointing out my silly mistake. I appreciate the answer. However, I haven’t gotten into integrals yet. I was hoping I could tackle that problem without integrals whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof by Ramiro works fine, but since I see from the comments that you haven't gotten to integration yet, you can also reason as follows.

The Lebesgue measure can be defined as the infimum of the sum of lengths of open intervals covering a set.  Therefore if $0<m(A)<\infty$, then there are intervals $(a_i,b_i)$ with $$\bigcup_i (a_i,b_i)\supseteq A$$ and
$$\sum_{i} b_i-a_i<2m(A)\text{.}$$
But then if $x\in A$, $x^2\in A$, which implies $x^2\in (a_i,b_i)$ for some $i$, and therefore $x\in (\sqrt{a_i},\sqrt{b_i})$.  We therefore have
$$\bigcup_i (\sqrt{a_i},\sqrt{b_i})\supseteq A$$ and so
$$m(A)\leq \sum_i \sqrt{b_i}-\sqrt{a_i}\leq 
\sum_{i} \frac{b_i-a_i}{\sqrt{b_i}+\sqrt{a_i}} < 
\sum_i\frac{b_i-a_i}{2}<m(A),$$
a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't have your idea when attempting the problem, but your solution makes total sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

> Let $A\subset(1, \infty)$ be a measurable set satisfying the following property : $x \in A$ iff $x^2 \in A$. Then $m(A)=0$ or $m(A)=\infty$.

Here is a simple proof.

**Proof**: Since $x \in A$ iff $x^2 \in A$, note that the functions $x\mapsto 1_A(x)$ and $x\mapsto 1_A(x^2)$ are identical. Then, by the Theorem of Change of Variable, we have
$$
m(A)= \int_1^\infty 1_A(y)dy = \int_1^\infty 1_A(x^2)(2x)dx = \int_1^\infty 1_A(x)(2x)dx \geqslant \int_1^\infty 1_A(x)(2)dx = \\ = 2 m(A)
$$
So $2 m(A) \leqslant  m(A)$. So  $m(A)=0$ or $m(A)=\infty$.
$\square$